Differential Riccati equation for infinite time horizon optimal control
Can I solve the infinite time horizon problem with the differential Riccati equation instead of the algebraic equation? As far as I know, considering the normal LTI system as $\dot{x} = Ax +Bu$ with the const function in the form of $J=\int_0^\infty (x^TQx + u^TRu)dt$, then the DRE will be like:
\begin{equation}
-\dot{P}(t) = P(t)A + A^TP(t) - P(t)BR^{-1}B^TP(t) + Q
\end{equation}
By considering a simple case like $A=1, B=1, Q=1, R=1$, then DRE will become $-\dot{P}(t) = -P^2(t) + 2P(t) + 1$ and converges to ($1-\sqrt{2}$) which is its stable equilibrium point and it is negative. By using ARE the steady state value for Riccati state is ($1+\sqrt{2}$) which is the unstable equilibrium point for the DRE. It is also the stable equilibrium point for the adjoint of the same DRE but I don't know how they are connected

Note that for finite horizon LQR, with time horizon $T$, one would actually start at $P(T)$ and use $-\dot{P}(t)$ to solve it backwards in time, until $P(0)$.
For determining "stability" of the, in this case two, equilibrium points one can use the following change of variables $X(\tau) = P(T-\tau)$, such that the "initial"/boundary condition is $X(0)=P(T)$ and dynamics is solved forward in "time"/$\tau$ instead of backwards, to make it more intuitive for determining stability/which equilibria are attractors. For $\tau>0$ the dynamics of $X(\tau)$ is given by $\dot{X}(\tau) = -X^2(\tau) + 2\,X(\tau) + 1$. The dynamics, and thus also the signs of the Jacobians at the equilibria, for local stability analysis, are negated, compared to the dynamics of $P(t)$. So your concluded local stability of the two equilibria are actually the opposite, with $(1+\sqrt{2})$ being the stable equilibrium and $(1-\sqrt{2})$ the unstable equilibrium from perspective of how one should solve for $P(t)$ to solve an LQR problem.
In general the algebraic Riccati equation will have multiple solution, one which is negative definite, possibly multiple that are indefinite and one that is positive definite; with the positive definite being the only one with a stable equilibrium.

Yes, you can. The validity of this procedure can be proven by using the following sequence of arguments, which I am not going to prove here because of its length. The general idea is the following:

Start with the differential Riccati equation
\begin{equation}
-\dot{P}(t) = P(t)A + A^TP(t) - P(t)BR^{-1}B^TP(t) + Q,\ P(T)=Q_T
\end{equation}
on $[0,T]$ and prove that there is a unique positive definite solution for any $Q_T\succeq0$.
Show that this solution can be uniquely extended to $(-\infty,T)$.
Show that the differential Riccati equation is, in fact, a contraction meaning that there is a globally attracting fixed point for its dynamics as $t\to-\infty$.
Show that this fixed point must be the positive semidefinite solution to the associated ARE.

In other words, just pick any initial positive semidefinite condition for the differential Riccati equation and integrate it backwards-in-time long enough to recove the solution of the ARE.
If you want the tedchnical details:

Kleinman, "Suboptimal Design of Lienar Regulators Systems Subject to Computer Storage Limitations"
Kalman, "Contributions to the Theory of Optimal Control"

